# Why does the generic parameter <T> change to <S> in some methods

Tags: java, generics

This is the class I'm working with in a past exam:

```
   class CyclicQueue<T> {

     private T data[] = (T[]) new Object[100]; // max 100 items

     private int items = 0, start = 0, next = 0;

     public boolean isEmpty() { return items == 0; }

     public void push(T item) {

       if(items < data.length) {

       data[next++] = item;

       if(next == data.length) { next = 0; }

       items++;
     }
   }

   public T pop() {

     T item = data[start++];

     if(start == data.length) { start = 0; }

       items--;

       return item;
     }
   }
```

As you can see the generic parameter used is `<T>`

However, in a subsequent question:

Q) In the box below, implement a generic method called emptyList which accepts a
generic CyclicQueue, and remove all items until it is empty.

The answer is this:

```
public <S> void emptyList(CyclicQueue<S> queue) {
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) { queue.pop(); }
}
```

I got the same answer but using `<T>` instead of `<S>`. I googled this and found `<S>` stands for a secondary type to the first, `<T>`. From what I can see the type hasn't changed, so why has the generic parameter?

Comment: Probably no particular reason.

Comment: The typename can be called anything. The programmer probably got up to get coffee and came back only to call it S

Comment: How can the line `private T data[] = (T[]) new Object[100];` ever work?  Unless `T` is `Object`, you are casting an `Object[]` to a subclass array.

Comment: At runtime T will be Object so not cast exception will occur

Answer (score 6):

It has changed the type parameter because this method can operate on any `CyclicQueue`, not
just a `CyclicQueue<T>`.

It could also be written as

```
public void emptyList(CyclicQueue<?> queue) {
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) { queue.pop(); }
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right.. and I often see like this..

Comment: Cheers. In the version I posted in the original question, is the <S> necessary in the method modifier?

Comment: @user2256772 no you can use a ? instead but compilers will issue warnings if you do not have anything there.

Answer (score 3):

It's a type not necessarily related to `T`.  If you have:

```
class CyclicQueue<T> {
    public T foo(CyclicQueue<T> x) {...}
    public <S> S bar(CyclicQueue<S> y) {...}
}
```

`foo` can take only cyclic queues of its own type (`T`), but `bar` can take a `CyclicQueue` of any type.

Comment: Is this because the method is likely to be outside of the CyclicQueue class?

Comment: No, it's likely because it should be *inside* the CyclicQueue class. It's logically related and may need to access private instance variables, so it needs to be in the same class, but `T` already has a meaning inside that class, so you need to choose a different identifier.  There's nothing special about `T` or `S`, they're just commonly used names. You could have declared the `class CyclicQueue<Wibble> {... public <Flibbertigibbet> void foo(CyclicQueue<Flibbertigibbet>x){...}}`.

Answer (score 0):

emptyList has its own parameter type and it actually could use the same parameter type name `T`

```
public <T> void emptyList(CyclicQueue<T> queue) {
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) { queue.pop(); }
}
```

but compiler would give a warning `The type parameter T hides parameter T` because it makes impossible to use class parameter type inside this method, eg

```
public <T> void emptyList(CyclicQueue<T> queue) {
    T e = data[0];  <-- ambiguous
    ...
```